# How does the XCVM architecture ensure the absoluteness principle described

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Very early on in this specification it says that "XCM is designed around four 'A's:"

One if which is "Absolute: XCM messages are guaranteed to be delivered and interpreted accurately, in order and in a timely fashion."

What i find most curious is how the delivery and order of these messages are guaranteed. Or wether these are actually assumptions as its only "designed around" the four A's instead of "functions according to".
Any lead on where to looks is appreciated.

felix

source: https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format

edit:

Here is a great resource: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-xcm

A channel must be opened and i assume it will be FIFO and there is a queue to ensure it.
Alot of basic XCM questions can be answered here.

Comment: Great question.  I am trying to wire `IBC` protocol with `trait ExportXcm`. ` in order and in a timely fashion` are very unclear. Just as real example which requires an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I try to answer your question with the code of XCM delivery process via HRMP.

Your focus is on **"in order"**, so we pay attention to whether the order of the messages changes, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. When you send an XCM via HRMP, it will be [inserted into `OutboundXcmpMessages`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs#L544), no change in order.
2. Then take messages [from `OutboundXcmpMessages` to `HrmpOutboundMessages`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L269), no change in order.
3. Then give the [`CollationInfo` which contains the XCM messages to relaychain](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L969), no change in order.
4. Then the receiver chain [received XCM messages from `InherentData`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L355), no change in order.
5. Then these messages are [sorted by blockNumber and paraId](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L856). Please note [this sort](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/btree/map.rs.html#2115) is stable, it does not change the order of messages which in the same block sent by the same chain.
6. Then these messages will be [inserted into `InboundXcmpMessages`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.37/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs#L1010) and then be dispatched in this order, no change in order.

Comment: This answers HRMP specifically, so not XCM and XCVM in general. Parity works on bridges and lite channels.  So may be author asked specifically about HRMP or HRPM can be example of ordering.

Comment: XCM works with VMP, HRMP, XCVM, etc. It is meaningless to only talk about XCM or XCVM.

Comment: Lite channels and bridges. You may look into `ExportXcm`. How bridges will enforce `absolutes`? I have several ideas, but would better want `absolutes` relaxed or RFCed so that can put XCM on top of arbitrary bridge. So that may be not what quetion is aboud so.

Comment: It is accurate to say XCM is "designed around" these 4 As, as XCM is a language independent from the data transport layer. It is "designed around" Absoluteness in the sense that it can only be expected to function properly when used atop a transport and execution layer which provides that guarantee.

Comment: Worth adding to xcm-format spec. So it feels that strict follow of these absolutes leads to slowness or queue stoppage. And one XCM message can Export/SendXcm over many transports at once, so not sure how far absolutes can reach.

Comment: I second Rob's comment; the four A's mentioned here are more accurately understood as design assumptions, rather than guarantees that XCM provides.

Answer (score 0):

My current interpretation of this `Absolute` next.

Setup best infrastructure possible with safest configuration which make XCM messages slower and higher cost, but best robustness.

Optimization can be done later.